# Selecting all objects (alt + click) connected to circuit does not work for off sheet connectors and net labels simultaneously

Tags: altium

[image: Alt + click on VCC net label]

I'm trying to use off sheet connectors for my schematic along with net labels, but when I try to display all wires connected to the same net via Alt+Click, they don't show Off sheet connector with same name. But they are one net (same net colors).